2PL: when to lock and unlock?
How do I know if a schedule is 2PL compliant? If not, how do I make it 2PL compliant?
S = r1(x) r2(y) w1(z) r2(x) r3(x) w2(z) r1(y) w2(y) w1(x)

When I do a lock upgrade do I re-enter the growth phase? When should I start freeing up resources?
